# Ubuntu 12.04 server: new kernels never used

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, grub2, kernel

I have three servers, all running Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS. When installed, the kernel is given a relatively small partition of around 227MB. When new kernels are released, they are installed, and Grub appears to update, but when the machine is rebooted the old kernel is still used.

The end result is that the kernel partition fills up with unused kernel versions, and I end up running out of space on the partition.

I've tried a range of things to try to get the servers to boot with the newest kernel, but with no luck.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? One possibility is some sort of confusion between Grub 1 and Grub 2, as I have both grub.cfg and menu.lst files.

Comment: What's the currently running Kernel version? Type `uname -a` to know it.
Also mention your current GRUB version; use `grub-install -v` to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embarrassingly, this was a simple matter of grub-legacy being installed, and needing to install grub2. Having said that, I'm not sure why grub legacy refused to acknowledge new kernels, but installing grub2 fixed the problem.

grub-legacy had replaced grub2 when a list of installed applications was copied over from a previous server.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must be using the old GRUB (grub-legacy). Install the newer version by following this Wiki: [Grub2/Upgrading](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading)
2. Reboot.
3. Now, update the system using 'Software Updater/Update Manager'.
4. Reboot and you must be able to use the new Kernel.